# Variational Inference: Ising Model

Tags: bayesian, image-processing, variational-bayes, approximate-inference

I am self learning Variational Inference. Currently I am reading the chapter 21 book from Murphy [1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262018020) and trying to understand the Ising model (21.3.2). 
The Ising model here is used as denoising technique to turn a gray valued image into a binary image.

The model is described as follows: assuming a latent variable $x_i \in \{-1, +1\}$, the joint model form is $p(\textbf{x}, \textbf{y}) = p(\textbf{x})p(\textbf{y}|\textbf{x})$, where $\textbf{y}$ denotes the gray values of the image and $\textbf{x}$ denotes the binary values of the corresponding pixels. The prior is 
$$p(\textbf{x}) \propto \exp(E_0(\textbf{x})),$$
$$E_0(\textbf{x}) = -\sum_{i=1}^{D}\sum_{j\in Nb(i)}W_{i,j}x_ix_j,$$
where $W$ is a weighting matrix (usually positive), and $Nb(i)$ denotes the first-degree hidden neighbors of pixel $i$.

Then, the author goes on and defines the likelihood as
$$p(\textbf{y}|\textbf{x}) = \prod_{i}p(y_i|x_i) = \exp(\sum_{i}-L_i(x_i)).$$ 
Finally, the posterior is presented as
$$p(\textbf{x}|\textbf{y}) \propto \exp(-E(\textbf{x})),$$
$$E(\textbf{x}) = E_0(\textbf{x}) - \sum_{i}L(x_i).$$

I do not follow what $L(\cdot)$ here represents, how the author arrived to the likelihood in that form, and how the posterior is determined since it should be intractable.

Answer (score 4):

> I do not follow what $L(\cdot)$ here represents

$L_i$ represents the log-likelihood of observing grayscale value $y_i$ if the binary value is $x_i$:

$$L_i(x_i) = \log p(y_i|x_i)$$

You can easily verify that taking exponential of sum of log-likelihoods equals taking product of likelihoods.

> How the posterior is determined since it should be intractable

There is nothing intractable about writing down the posterior formula. **Computing the posterior is intractable**: you cannot compute it without evaluating all the possible values of $\mathbf{x}$, which are needed to compute the normalizer $Z$ in (21.40). That is why we need to use the approximate variational inference.

---

This [IPython notebook](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/guyrt.github.io/notebooks/Ising_model.ipynb) might also provide you more insight.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did a mistake in copying the likelihood, the sum goes over the exponent and not as I put it before. I have corrected it.

Comment: @mgbacher No, the sum is **inside** the exponential (check (21.39) in the book). I corrected that for you in the question text, but I see you reverted it again...

Comment: @mgbacher Product is converted to sum of powers $\exp(a+b)=\exp(a) \exp (b)$.

Comment: No problem. Just for the reference, I corrected the equation in the question text once again.

Answer (score 1):

The notation for this section is pretty bad. The $L(.)$ is first used to refer to the objective function to be maximized (ELBO). Then, as the accepted answer states, it is all of a sudden used for the ***log-likelihood***.

It also doesn't help that the formula in the book (at least in my version, and it seems the original poster's as well) is incorrect and has the equation as:

$$
p(\textbf{y}|\textbf{x}) = \prod_{i}p(y_i|x_i) = \sum_{i}\exp(-L_i(x_i)).
$$